# Savitzky-Golay filtering (not smoothing) in real time

Tags: digital-filters, filtering

I would like to filter some data in an online sense i.e.

$$y(t) = a0 + a1*y(t-1) + a2*y(t-2) + ... $$

the order not important.

My understanding of the SG is that it is really a smoother - I have to take some point and use points around it, in this case I would end up with e.g.

$$y(t-3) = a0 + a1*y(t-1) + b1*y(t+1) + ...$$

which is not ideal as my filter cannot 'see' into the future.

[This article here](https://gregstanleyandassociates.com/whitepapers/FaultDiagnosis/Filtering/LeastSquares-Filter/leastsquares-filter.htm) suggests coefficients for the SG that match what I require, but I cannot find any other resource on the internet.

Can somebody please point out what I should be looking for and/or where the coefficients in that link come from?

Is it plausible to just mirror the data around y(t) and use traditional SG?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from playing around. They are easily computed with `scipy.savgol_coeffs` e.g.

```
In [0]: signal.savgol_coeffs(7, 1, pos=0, use='dot')
Out[1]: array([ 0.46428571,  0.35714286,  0.25      ,  0.14285714,  0.03571429,
       -0.07142857, -0.17857143])
```

Matches the values in the website.